# MassTransit saga using AzureServiceBus silently fails

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit

I am trying to create a MassTransit saga using AzureServiceBus and .NET Core.

I have an ASP.NET Core application that is successfully sending messages to the queue. It has this configuration in the Startup.cs:

```csharp
services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host(
        new Uri("https://zzz.servicebus.windows.net/"),
        h =>
        {
            h.TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
            h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            h.RetryLimit = 1;
            h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "xxx");
        });
        
    cfg.RequiresSession = true;
}));

EndpointConvention.Map<MassTransit.POC.Shared.IPurchasePolicyMessage>(
    new Uri("https://zzz.servicebus.windows.net/masstransitqueue"));

services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
```

and this code in a controller sending the message:

```csharp
var sendEndpoint = await _sendEndpointProvider.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("https://zzz.servicebus.windows.net/masstransitqueue"));

await
  sendEndpoint.Send<IPurchasePolicyMessage>(
    new
    {
      QuoteNumber = policyNumber,
      CorrelationId = NewId.NextGuid().ToString("D")
    }, context =>
    {
      context.SetSessionId(context.Message.CorrelationId.ToString());
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I've got a separate .NET Core console application which is receiving the IPurchasePolicyMessage. It has this configuration in the Program.cs:

```csharp
var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(
        new Uri("https://zzz.servicebus.windows.net/"),
        h =>
        {
            h.TransportType = TransportType.AmqpWebSockets;
            h.OperationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            h.RetryLimit = 1;
            h.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "xxx");
        });

    cfg.RequiresSession = true;

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "masstransitqueue", e =>
    {
        e.RequiresSession = true;
        //e.Consumer<PurchasePolicyConsumer>();
        e.Saga<PurchasePolicySaga>(new MessageSessionSagaRepository<PurchasePolicySaga>());
    });
});

bus.Start();
```

and the PurchasePolicySaga is defined as:

```csharp
public class PurchasePolicySaga :
    ISaga,
    InitiatedBy<IPurchasePolicyMessage>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IPurchasePolicyMessage> context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Processing policy number {context.Message.QuoteNumber} in saga.");
    }
}
```

the Consume method here is never called. There are no errors, there is no activity related to the incoming message in the logs, just nothing happens. Can someone please tell me how to find why?

I strongly suspect the issue relates to sessions, as when I change my saga to a simple consumer, remove the "RequiresSession" flags and delete the queue to allow MassTransit to recreate it, it works. However, as sessions are required for an AzureServiceBus-based MassTransit saga, I'm a bit stuck.

**Further Investigation**

Looking at the messages in the Azure dashboard, I see that the messages are being sent to the queue. This screenshot shows 3 messages:

[image: azure queue screenshot]

However, there are no messages on the topic:

[image: azure topic screenshot]

I should expect corresponding messages on the topic shouldn't I? Also, it doesn't seem right that the subscription here has Sessions Disabled?

Comment: Where is the `bus.Start` being called?

Comment: What do you see in the log?

Comment: Are you setting the SessionId when you send the message to the saga queue?

Comment: @ChrisPatterson, no I'm not. Do I need to, and if so, how do I do it?  

I've just tried adding a SessionId guid property to the IPurchasePolicyMessage and set it in my Send but that made no difference.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev, I have the `bus.Start()` in my code, but omitted it from here for brevity. I've now added it back in above.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev, I have updated my post to include the logs. They show the message being sent from the ASP.NET application but show nothing on the console application side.

Comment: I just realized you're using .NET Core - you need to use the full framework to use sessions.

Comment: Ah - that's disappointing, looks like MassTransit isn't for us then. Thanks @ChrisPatterson. Can you post this as an answer, and I'll accept it?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to figure out why it isn't working in the .NET core client. Doesn't make sense to me why it's failing to register a session handler. I'll let you know.

Comment: okay, i figured it out. I'll publish an update to the azure .net core libraries in the next couple days.

Comment: the pre-release packages are working with sagas for .NET core, fyi: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core/5.2.2.1822-develop

Comment: Great - thank you @ChrisPatterson! It is working for us now. Can you post this as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 0):

To use sessions with Azure Service Bus, you have to set the SessionId of the message sent/published so that Azure will create a session for it.

```
await InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(message, context =>
{
    context.SetSessionId(message.CorrelationId.ToString());
});
```

You can see a working unit test example here:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit.AzureServiceBusTransport.Tests/Session_Specs.cs

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @ChrisPatterson. I've tried specifying a SessionId, and I still see the same result (ie, the Consume method is not called). I've updated my question to include the code I added for the SessionId. Can you see anything else I've missed?

Comment: is this a state machine saga? If so, you need to e.StateMachineSaga(...) to register it.

Comment: No, it's not a state machine saga.

Comment: we've noticed that in the Azure dashboard, there are messages on the queue, but not on the corresponding topic. I've updated my question with more detail on this. It doesn't seem right?